# HTTP 404 status code (Not Found) shown as 302

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to retrieve the HTTP status code of a list of URLs in python, using the following piece of code:

```
try:
    r = requests.head(testpoint_url)
    print(testpoint_url+" : "+str(r.status_code))
    # prints the int of the status code.
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("failed to connect")
```

Surprisingly, for some URLs, I get `302` status code while if browsed by a browser, you see it showing a 404 code!

[image]

What is going on? How can I get the real status code (e.g. 404)?

Comment: The server may send you any error page it wants and an independent status code. In this case it would seem the server is just doing it wrong by displaying 404 on the page, but sending 302.

Comment: So you are saying the 404 is wrong, not really 302?!

Comment: I'm just saying that the displayed code seems to differ from the sent code. Whoever implements the server backend may decide to set whatever status code he wants. The backend developer may even decide to send status  404 for an existing resource.

Comment: Browsers usually will automatically follow a 302 redirect, so maybe the 404 is from the followed link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

302 is an HTTP redirection. A web browser will follow the redirect to the URL reported in the `Location` response header. When requesting that next URL, it will have its own response code, which can include 404.

Your Python code does not follow the redirect, which would explain why it gets the original 302 instead.

Per the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) documentation:

[Redirection and History](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

> By default Requests will perform location redirection for all verbs **except HEAD**.
>
> We can use the `history` property of the Response object to track redirection.
>
> The `Response.history` list contains the `Response` objects that were created in order to complete the request. The list is sorted from the oldest to the most recent response.
>
> ...
>
> If you’re using GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE, you can disable redirection handling with the `allow_redirects` parameter:
>
> ```
> >>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/', allow_redirects=False)
>
> >>> r.status_code
> 301
>
> >>> r.history
> []
> ```
>
> **If you’re using HEAD, you can enable redirection as well**:
>
> ```
> >>> r = requests.head('https://github.com/', allow_redirects=True)
>
> >>> r.url
> 'https://github.com/'
>
> >>> r.history
> [<Response [301]>]
> ```

So, in your code, change this:

```
r = requests.head(testpoint_url)
```

To this:

```
r = requests.head(testpoint_url, allow_redirects=True)
```

Then `r.status_code` will be the final status code (ie, 404) after all redirects have been followed.

Comment: Great! Problem sovled